# Babruvahana in Kurukshetra

Tags: mahabharata, arjuna, kurukshetra

As we all know about Babruvahana, the son of Arjuna from Chitrangada. I want to know why he did not took part in Mahabharata War(Kurukshetra). On researching, I just got one answer that Chitrangada did not allow him. But I want to know more about this. Does any one here have any specific good reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out to be its already answered on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chitr%C4%81ngad%C4%81)

*Arjuna travelled the length and breadth of India during his term of exile. His wanderings took him to ancient Manipura, an almost mystic kingdom renowned for its natural beauty. There, he met Chitrāngadā, the daughter of the king of Manipura, and moved to her father Chitrabahana to seek her hand in marriage. Her father demurred on the plea that, according to the customs of his people, the children born of Chitrāngadā would be heirs to Manipura; he could not allow his heirs to be taken away from Manipura. Arjuna agreed to the stipulation that he would take away neither his wife Chitrāngadā nor any children born by her from Manipura, and wed the princess on this premise.*